# Button Click in Gridview to Update SQL value

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview pulling the values customerName, acctNum, phoneNum, city, address and lastLeak.  The data all pulls up great I pull up any lastLeak thats 5 years or older.  Then I have a button on the right that once a driver does the check he hits that button and for that row updates the lastLeak to today's date.  For some reason I can't get it to work I know it has to be close can anyone shine some light.

Here is my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="lastLeakCheck" Width="950px" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="customerName" HeaderText="customerName" SortExpression="customerName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="acctNum" HeaderText="acctNum" SortExpression="acctNum" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="phoneNum" HeaderText="phoneNum" SortExpression="phoneNum" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="city" HeaderText="city" SortExpression="city" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="address" HeaderText="address" SortExpression="address" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="lastLeak" HeaderText="lastLeak" SortExpression="lastLeak" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="UpdateDate" HeaderText="Update Date" ShowHeader="True" Text="Completed"   />



    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="lastLeakCheck" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=propane;User ID=id;Password=pass;Integrated Security=True"
     SelectCommand="SELECT customerName, acctNum, phoneNum, city, address, lastLeak from custInfoWHERE lastLeak &lt;= CONVERT(datetime, '4-6-2012' )ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, lastLeak) ASC" ></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And my click event for the row:

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

```
    if (e.CommandName == "UpdateDate")
    {

        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

        cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=propane;User ID=id;Password=pass;Integrated Security=True");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE custInfo SET lastLeak='4/7/2017' WHERE customerName='@customerName'", cn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerName", row.Cells[0].Text);

        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: I tagged C#, mysql, .net and gridview figured that was the closest?

Comment: ASP was/is missing! Note that the tags are for finding questions to answer and avoiding those we don't. So the Tags are used in the questions overview. Once I got here I could see the ASP in the code but the trip was a waste..

Comment: I updated thank you...